# Why do I get a "duplicate children" exception when creating GridPane children?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to dynamically create a GridPane view in JavaFX. The issue is when trying to add the children to the pane I get a "duplicate children" exception.

Here is how I adding the children to the pane:

```
    GridPane gridView = new GridPane();
    for(int i = 0; i < mobster.getActions().size(); i++) {
        MobsterVisualWrapper actionWrapper = new MobsterVisualWrapper(mobster.getActionList().get(i));

        gridView.add(actionWrapper.getNode(), 0, i);
        gridView.add(actionWrapper.getLabel(), 1, i);
    }
    
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        queuedActionsBorderPane.setCenter(gridView);
    });



public static class MobsterVisualWrapper{
        private final Label actionLabel;
        private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(-1.0f);
        private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        private Node node;
        
        public MobsterVisualWrapper(AbstractAction action) {
            actionLabel = new Label(action.getName());
            actionLabel.setDisable(true);
            node = new Label("-");
            action.setVisualWrapper(this);
        }
        
        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            if(running) {
                setNode(progressBar);
            } else {
                setNode(new ImageView());
            }
        }
        
        public void setFailed() {
            imageView.setId("actionViewFailed");
            setNode(imageView);
        }
        
        public void setComplete() {
            imageView.setId("actionViewComplete");
            setNode(imageView);
        }
        
        /**
         * Sets the node that will show the current status of the action
         * @param node the node to show the status
         */
        private void setNode(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }
        
        /**
         * @return the node to show the status of the action
         */
        private Node getNode() {
            return node;
        }
        
        public Label getLabel() {
            return actionLabel;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to add a new row each loop iteration with two columns.

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be caused by the code you posted (because you are clearly just adding two labels on each iteration of the loop, which you have just created). Check the exception is being thrown from where you think, and add logging if necessary to figure out which node is being added to the scene graph twice. If that doesn't solve it, you'll probably need to provide a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* **and** *complete*).

Comment: I guess `action.setVisualWrapper(this)` looks a bit suspicious. What is that for? Are you using that to add the UI components somewhere else at a later stage?

Comment: Adding the entire stack trace to your question would make this a lot easier to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code actually does work and no longer throws the exception. I think before I was setting GridPane.setConstraints along with the add method which may have caused some issues. I thought the issue was still persisting despite removing this but I guess that isn't the case. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.